# StreamSocketListener in windows server 2008

Tags: win-universal-app

I want to implement `SocketActivity Trigger` in my `UWP` application, so I should have a `StreamSocketListener` calss in server side, My Windows server is 2008, is there anyway to implement server side on it? or if not is there any free online windows server that I can test my App?because this just a research and I don't have any other windows server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to implement SocketActivity Trigger in my UWP application, so I should have a StreamSocketListener calss in server side, My Windows server is 2008, is there anyway to implement server side on it? or if not is there any free online windows server that I can test my App?because this just a research and I don't have any other windows server.

The **minimum** supported server for [StreamSocketListener](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br226906) class is **Windows Server 2012**. So it cannot be implemented on your Windows Server 2008. However, [StreamSocketListener](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br226906) class is not only supported on Windows Server, **it is also supported on Windows 8 or Windows 10**.

So if you don't have a supported Windows server, you can implement [StreamSocketListener](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br226906) class on Windows 8 or Windows 10 for your test purpose. I am implementing [StreamSocketListener](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br226906) class on my Windows 10 for testing [SocketActivity Trigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn806009) and it works fine.